# Convert date range to separate numeric dates in JQuery

Tags: jquery, date-format, date-range

In a web app I'm building, a 3rd party widget returns date range in the following format.

JQuery to return dates:
`$("#date_range").val()`
returns
`November 21, 2018 - November 23, 2018`

How can I convert the returned date to two separate Y-m-d variables in JQuery?

Comment: In order to help you with this we'd need to know what date range library you're using, and also how you're using it in code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, you want to get the start date and end date into two variables in `Y-m-d` format. Currently by using `$("#date_range").val()` you are getting a single date string (e.g. `November 21, 2018 - November 23, 2018).

You can simply split the date string and use the following function to get dates into two separate variables in Y-m-d format.

```js
var dateString = 'November 21, 2018 - November 23, 2018'; // date received from $("#date_range").val()


var startDate = getDateYMD(dateString.split(' - ')[0]);  // return 2018-10-21
var endDate = getDateYMD(dateString.split(' - ')[1]);    // return 2018-10-23



function getDateYMD(strDate) {

  var date = new Date(strDate)
  yr = date.getFullYear(),
    month = date.getMonth(),
    day = date.getDate(),
    newDate = yr + '-' + month + '-' + day;

  console.log(newDate);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```